# Async web programming in python on windows

Tags: python, asynchronous

I would like to do some async web programming in python. I would like to use http://www.tornadoweb.org, but my code has to run on windows. My next try was [TwistedWeb](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedWeb), but the Resource-based programming model does not fit my needs very well. I would prefer a Flask-like toolkit. I tried to dig through various other options, but most async python libs seem to be restricted to Unix plattforms.

Does somebody know a python web framework which works like Flask (ie. uses routing) but works async?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a peek at gevent, flask even has integration for it.